# How to prevent mpldatacursor from reappearing after right-clicking?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpldatacursor import datacursor

x = np.arange(10)
y = x**2
line = plt.plot(x, y, 'bs')
datacursor(line)

plt.show()
```

If I click on a data point, the datacursor appears. I can switch between the points using shift+arrow keys. If I right-click the datacursor, it disappears, as it should. But if I then again press shift+right, it reappears, which I think it shouldn't. Doesn't seem like a big problem here, but with several lines I want to be able to have a datacursor on one line, remove it and check another line, but the old reappears if I browse the new one using shift+arrow keys.

How to get rid of this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get what I wanted: In the mpldatacursor folder there is a datacursor.py file for the datacursor class. Search the file (backup) and open it. Find

```
def update(self, event, annotation):
```

copy the whole method, paste it as a new method and rename it to

```
def update_no_set_vis(self, event, annotation):
```

or whatever you like. The behavior I described in my post seemed to be intended by the developer, as visible from the lines

```
# In case it's been hidden earlier...
annotation.set_visible(True)
```

in this method. Comment out or remove this part (of course only in the newly created method!). Now, search the method

```
def _increment_index(self, di=1):
```

which defines what happens if shift+arrow is pressed. Edit the last line of this function:

```
self.update(event, self._last_annotation)
```

to:

```
self.update_no_set_vis(event, self._last_annotation)
```

Reinstall mpldatacursor by

> python setup.py install

in the parent folder. Now, the datacursor does not show up again by keypress after being removed.